Is adding plugins to WhatsApp possible?
I did a good search on Internet to see if it is possible to add plugins to my original WhatsApp app...unfortunately I found nothing...
I want to add a plugin to organize a specific group..
Add sections and bots... just much more organised than the normal group or society on the app it self.
I'm accepting all answers with good information and guidelines.
Did long research... expected to find source code or at least the ability to add plugins to the main app.
Results: 404 not found XD.
